# Multi-select dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on creating a website using node.js and express. I want to add a multi-select dropdown box. I have a Javascript object which contains a variety of properties and would like to populate the dropdown box with all the property values. I would also like to be able to add new options to the dropdown and have them visible without having to refresh the page. Is there someway to accomplish this? Perhaps using JQuery? I would appreciate if someone could provide an example.

I've tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ehynds/akhyp/light/) example, but I would like to have a multi select checkbox for the dropdown. The example requires the user to press `ctrl` while clicking to select multiple options.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code. Search for cascading select ajax

Comment: The code I have is shown in the hyperlink

Comment: With 380 rep you should know better

Comment: @mplungjan most of my experience is in Android and backend development, and I am new to frontend development. With ~36000 rep perhaps you can provide a solid solution.

Comment: This is not a "gimme teh codez" site and you have not even provided us with a glimpse of your JS object. I can of course help you, but help US help you by sharing your code and perhaps add your object to your jsfiddle.net. [See here why](http://sscce.org). By the way, there is a "select all" link on your example. What do you mean by "multi select box"? Make a drawing or something

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#select_id").append("<option value='value'>name</option>");
```